# RLMResults sortedArrayUsingComparator behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, realm

I've got a one to many property that returns a `RLMResults` for an `objectsWhere:` query. I need to sort this data by linking up uid's in a linked list fashion (each object has a `previousId` property which points to the `uid` property of the object before it).

*I can do this with an `NSArray` with `sortedArrayUsingComparator` like this:*

```
myArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MyRLMObject *obj1, MyRLMObject *obj2) {
    if ([obj1.parentTileId isEmpty]) { // head of the list must be sorted first
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if ([obj1.previousId isEqualToString:obj2.uid]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
}];
```

However, RLMResults only has sorting based on 1 property. **Is there a way to get the same logic with RLMResults? As a fallback solution how can I convert RLMResults into NSArray to perform this?**

Comment: Realm is tracking adding the ability to sort via a comparison block in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1265. If you need to convert an RLMArray into an NSArray, you can call `valueForKey:@"self"` on it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow that